# PaperFab ripple issues

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use `paper-fab` element, but since I started using it I get some issues with its ripple effect.

1. After extending `paper-fab` the ripple effect becomes like rectangle
   (circle expected).
2. `paper-fab` with `label` instead of `icon` cause its ripple to
   uncover little bit from the bottom.
3. `paper-fab` ripple is working as expected with icon.

After digging in its shadow dom I could solve the second issue by adding `height: 100%` to `div#clip` element inside its shadow dom [though I couldn't solve it by code, only by inspector :( ].

Unfortunately I couldn't find anyway to get the ripple effect work as expected after extending `paper-fab`.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a jsbin of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All issues mentioned above have been solved after updating to v0.4.0